# IKEv2, ESP PFS. Which packets includes the configuration?

Tags: networking, encryption, wireshark

i am investigating currently the IKEv2 protocol with ESP payload encryption. For ESP i want to use PFS with DH Group 5 (which works).
However, i am not able to figure out in which packet this settings is sent to the partner.

In the first two packets (IKE_SA_INIT) i am able to find the DH group for the IKE SA. I assume that the setting is sent in the 3rd/4th message (IKE AUTH) _since all the CHILD_SA relevant stuff is in it (ENC/AUTH algorithm). But i can't find it (i decrypted the packet using wireshark isakmp decryption).

Where is this setting hidden?
Thanks

Comment: If you're using PFS, then how did Wireshark decrypt it?

Comment: doesn't answer my question. however, as far as i know for the first 4 packets (2x IKE_SA_INIT, 2x IKE_AUTH) PFS is not relevant since PFS is only used for the next CHILD_SA rekeying. To decrypt IKE_AUTH packets i used the computed SK_Ei, SK_Er

Comment: The comment wasn't meant to answer the question, it was meant to ask one...

Answer (score 0):

The first Child SA is negotiated within the IKE_AUTH Payload. It's called SA[i|r]2 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296#section-1.2 . It's an extra SA Payload within the IKE_AUTH Payload.
The RFC states:

> Note that IKE_AUTH messages do not contain KEi/KEr or Ni/Nr payloads.
> Thus, the SA payloads in the IKE_AUTH exchange cannot contain
> Transform Type 4 (Diffie-Hellman group) with any value other than
> NONE.  Implementations SHOULD omit the whole transform substructure
> instead of sending value NONE.

To precisely answer your question: There is no PFS for the first CHILD_SA that is part of the IKE_AUTH exchanges. Any setting regarding PFS for CHILD_SAs only apply to CHILD_SA exchanges to create new CHILD_SAs after the initial exchanges.